# How to share an Image and Text on whatsapp to a specific number?

Tags: java, android

I already know how to send it on whatsapp but not to a number, the way I'm doing I got a list of contacts and I need to choose which one should I send. But I need to send the Message to a specific number.

```
private void WhatsAppShare(ChannelEvent event){
    Intent IntentW = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    IntentW.setType("text/plain");
    IntentW.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Denúncia :" + "\n\n" + model.getMessage() + "\n\n" + model.getTitle());
    IntentW.putExtra("jid", event.getId() +"@s.whatsapp.net");
    IntentW.setType("image/jpg");
    IntentW.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),selectedImage));
    //IntentW.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
    IntentW.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    IntentW.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    try {
        startActivity(IntentW);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

If I take the `ComponentName` works fine, and with, I get the whatsapp chat to this number but with no images or Text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a message to the particular user by using the following code,

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(context1, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File("ImageUrl")));
         sendIntent.putExtra("jid", whatsAppNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net");
         sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "whatsAppMessage");
         sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
         sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp.w4b");
         sendIntent.setType("image/*");
         startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Here "**com.whatsapp.w4b**" is used for the Business WhatsApp application if you want to use normal WhatsApp then you just need to change **com.whatsapp.w4b** to **com.whatsapp**

**whatsAppNumber** is a number to which you want to send the WhatsApp a message

and **ImageUrl** is the URL of the internal image path.

Above code will open your WhatsApp application with a given number in an image viewer after that you have to press button to send message.

Comment: Doesn't open a particular number if it's not WhatsApp for Business (tested with only regular WhatsApp)

Comment: @RivuChakraborty if you want to open in the normal whatsApp you need to change the package name of whatsApp as com.whatsapp .

Comment: Doesn't work, at least for normal WhatsApp